# postdoc position does not require letter of recommendation only contact details of referees. Should I still provide the letters?

Tags: application, postdocs, recommendation-letter

I'm applying for a postdoc position at ETH Zurich. 
For the application, the following requirements are listed:

- Letter of motivation
- CV and list of publications
- Electronic copies of university transcripts and certificates
- Contact details of two referees

They do not list letters of recommendation in their requirements.

This leads me to the following question: 
**Would it be better to provide letters of recommendation, even though they are not required?**

*Additional information:*

I know the professor and he knows me. 
In fact, it would be possible **to get four letters of recommendation** from leading scientists. 
I know that the professor knows and respects these scientists very much. 
I'm sure that most of the other applicants would not have this strong support behind them. This would be a chance to separate me from those. However, I'm unsure if it is not counterproductive since they explicitly stated that they only need the **contact information of two referees**.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to provide any letters of reference.

If you do they may well be ignored as they ask for the contact details of 2 referees. This means that they will contact those referees directly and get the information required in their own format as they wish.